# Why is the ROW keyword needed when constructing a row with one element, but not two?

Tags: postgresql, syntax, row

In PostgreSQL 11, the following expression

```
UPDATE test_table SET ("column_a","column_b") = ('value-a','value-b') WHERE "column_a" = 'value-c'
```

is accepted and performs the update.

But for a single column / value, like

```
UPDATE test_table SET ("column_a") = ('value-a') WHERE "column_a" = 'value-c'
```

it gives an error. `ROW` must be supplied, like

```
UPDATE test_table SET ("column_a") = ROW ('value-a') WHERE "column_a" = 'value-c'
```

Is there an explanation why this behavior was chosen? Is there an ambiguity if `ROW` is missing?

Comment: It's not typically helpful to ask why features are or are not in languages or particular versions of languages. It's the current output of a complex social process. Better to ask whether particular research-supported reasoning on your part is sensible re why features would be good or bad.

Answer (score 6):

As is often the case, the answer is to be found in documentation.

The [`UPDATE` reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-update.html) says, in particular:

> According to the standard, the source value for a parenthesized sub-list of target column names can be any row-valued expression yielding the correct number of columns. PostgreSQL only allows the source value to be a **row constructor** or a sub-`SELECT`.

whereas "row constructor" is [defined](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) like so:

> A row constructor is an expression that builds a row value (also called a composite value) using values for its member fields. A row constructor consists of the key word `ROW`, a left parenthesis, zero or more expressions (separated by commas) for the row field values, and finally a right parenthesis. [...] The key word `ROW` is optional when there is more than one expression in the list.

The last sentence kind of makes sense, because a single expression in parentheses is ambiguous by itself and can be confused with a simple parenthesised expression.

This syntax was introduced in [version 10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/10.0/) -- HT to ypercube™.